# new to java system cant find path

Tags: java

```
/**
 * @(#)ListFiles.java
 *
 * ListFiles application
 *
 * @author Jack
 * @version 1.00 2017/12/6
 */

public class ListFiles {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      java.io.File
      java.io.File listroot = new java.io.File("c:/");
      java.io.File[] files = listroot.listFiles();

      System.out.println("Print root files from c:");

      for (java.io.File file : files) {
         if (file.isDirectory())
            continue;
         System.out.println(file.getPath());
      }
   }
}
```

--------------------Configuration: ListFiles - JDK version 1.8.0_151  - --------------------
javac: file not found: src_listfiles.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: Please specify your reason if you are Downvoting.

Comment: Insufficient information ... please draft your question correctly and include all relevant details.

Comment: @LalitVerma http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ we don't use `javac` on text files. And this code doesn't compile. Also, can you tell me what the question is?

Comment: thanx for specifying reason, that's what i want from all downvoters so that their comment could help in future questions for other too :) @ElliottFrisch

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in your program , try this :

```
public class cn {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      java.io.File f;
      java.io.File listroot = new java.io.File("c:/");
      java.io.File[] files = listroot.listFiles();

      System.out.println("Print root files from c:");

      for (java.io.File file : files) {
         if (file.isDirectory())
            continue;
         System.out.println(file.getPath());
      }
   }
}
```

Above program working in Eclipse ide.